# UserTerritory2Association trigger test

Tags: trigger, unit-test, test-data-isolation

I have a trigger for UserTerritory2Association standard object like:

```
trigger MyUserTerritoryAssociationTrigger on UserTerritory2Association(after insert, after update,
after delete, after undelete) {
    //Trigger logic
}
```

And it works fine. The problem is, when I try to create a test class for this trigger, I'm not being able to create the test data for my tests. Specifically, I can't insert new UserTerritory2Association instances because I receive a run-time exception:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

The test code:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
private class UserTerritoryAssociationTriggerTest {

    static testMethod void testAfterInsert() {
        List<Territory2Type> territoryTypes = Test.loadData(Territory2Type.SObjectType, 'MyTestData');

        Territory2Model model = new Territory2Model(
            Name = 'Test',
            DeveloperName = 'Test');
        insert model;

        Territory2 territory = new Territory2(
            Name = 'test',
            DeveloperName = 'test',
            Territory2ModelId = model.Id,
            Territory2TypeId = territoryTypes[0].Id);
        insert territory;

        UserTerritory2Association association = new UserTerritory2Association(
            Territory2Id = territory.Id);
        Test.startTest();
        insert association; // Throws run-time  exception
        Test.stopTest();

        // Asserts go here
    }
}
```

I know that DML operations are not allowed with certain objects like Territory, however the first two DML statements in my test method seems to be working but I'm not sure if that has something to do with the exception in the third DML statement.

So here my questions:
Am I missing something? 
How can I avoid this exception? 
Is there a better way to create data for tests that are related to UserTerritory2Association's triggers.

Any help you could provide would be great.

Comment: don't you need a value for `userId` and `RoleInTerritory2` in the `new UserTerritory2Association(Territory2Id = territory.Id);` line

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to create data for tests that are related to UserTerritory2Association's triggers.

Refer to the snippet below!

```
@isTest
private class SL_Test_TerritoyTriggerAndBatch {

    private static final Id ACCOUNT_BROKER_RECORDTYPE = [Select Id, DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType='Account' and DeveloperName='Broker' LIMIT 1].Id;

    private static testMethod void territorryAssignmentToAccountsByTrigger() {

        Account objAccount = new Account(RecordTypeId = ACCOUNT_BROKER_RECORDTYPE, Name = 'Test Acc - 01', ShippingState = 'USA');
        insert objAccount;
        User usr = [Select id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        System.RunAs(usr)
        {
            Test.startTest();
               insertTestTerritory(objAccount.Id);
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }

    //@future
    private static void insertTestTerritory(Id AccId)
    {
        List<Territory2Type> terriType   = [SELECT id, DeveloperName from Territory2Type where  DeveloperName = 'Broker_Assignments' LIMIT 1];
        List<Profile> adminProfile = [select id, name from Profile where  name = 'System Administrator'];

        Territory2Model terrModel = new Territory2Model();
        terrModel .DeveloperName='ModelName'; // required field
        terrModel.Name = 'Name'; // required field
        insert terrModel ;

        Territory2 objTerr = new Territory2(DeveloperName = 'TestTerritory', Territory2ModelId=terrModel.Id, Name='TestTerritory', Territory2TypeId=terriType[0].Id);
        insert objTerr;

        ObjectTerritory2Association objObjectTerritory2Association = new ObjectTerritory2Association(ObjectId = AccId, Territory2Id =objTerr.Id, AssociationCause='Territory2Manual' );
        insert objObjectTerritory2Association;

        Profile p = [SELECT id, Name FROM Profile where name = 'System Administrator' ].get(0);  
        User u = new User(firstname= 'Test',
                  lastname='XXXX',
                  Alias='Test',
                  email = 'test1234@test.com',
                  username= 'test1234xxx@test.com', 
                  profileId= p.id, 
                  emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                  languagelocalekey='en_US',
                  localesidkey='en_US',
                  timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');
        insert u;

        User u2 = new User(firstname= 'Test',
                  lastname='XXXX',
                  Alias='Test',
                  email = 'test1234122@test.com',
                  username= 'test1234xxx123@test.com', 
                  profileId= p.id, 
                  emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                  languagelocalekey='en_US',
                  localesidkey='en_US',
                  timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');
        insert u2;


        UserTerritory2Association objUserTerritory2Association = new UserTerritory2Association(Territory2Id= objTerr.Id, UserId= u.Id, RoleInTerritory2='Sales / Marketing Manager');
        insert objUserTerritory2Association;

        UserTerritory2Association objUserTerritory2Association2 = new UserTerritory2Association(Territory2Id= objTerr.Id, UserId= u2.Id, RoleInTerritory2='Sales / Marketing Administrator');
        insert objUserTerritory2Association2;  

    }

}
```

Comment: hey Smriti - thanks for answering this -- A couple of tips - (1) community etiquette is not to prompt for upvotes or answer marking; we find that good answers get upvoted naturally without the solicitations. And (2) - it might be good to comment as to why your answer solves the problem rather than simply posting code (such as where the OP went astray) - this helps all of us learn and benefit from your knowledge